# How to save the result of d3.csv.parse to a global variable?

Tags: csv, d3.js

I have this

```
var result;
d3.csv("xxx.csv",function(data){
        csvResultParser(data);
});

function csvResultParser(data){
  //parse the data then assign it to result  
}
```

But I still have result as "undefined", any clues?

Comment: are there any errors in the javascript console, maybe it fails to load the file?

Answer (score 2):

The `d3.csv()` function is asynchronous. Thus, you have to wait for the data to be received before reading the `result` variable. This is the reason why, when dealing with asynchronous data, it is prefered to do everything inside the `d3.csv()` function instead of using global variables.

Comment: thanks for your reply~ So if I would like to use the result outside of that function, do you know a good way to work around with it with current function setting as d3.csv()?

Comment: You would have to call the function you want to use from inside the `d3.csv()` function.  If you use 'result' outside of it, it is as if you asked for a beer in a bar and started drinking it before the bartender even started serving it.