# How to load tsv file to use with D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to use a tsv file in my D3 projects. I have looked at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV

This is my code now after some help from the comments

```
d3.tsv.parse(d3.select("ballet.tsv").text(), function(d){
    d3.select("body").append("div")
        .text(d.year);
});
```

and my data looks like this

```
year    production  Company
1996    Impressions of Sophie (1996)    National Youth Ballet of Great Britain
1996    Lavender's Blue (1996)  National Youth Ballet of Great Britain
1940    Les Sylphides (1940)    The Vic-Wells Ballet
```

etc.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671865/how-to-save-the-result-of-d3-csv-parse-to-a-global-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lars pointed out in the comment, `d3.tsv.parse` is asynchronous, so all your code for `data` manipulation should be *wrapped* in a callback function (`accessor` argument in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#tsv_parse)). The basic code should be structured as follows:

```
d3.tsv.parse(d3.select("#tsv").text(), function(d){
    //The code below will be called for each row in the tsv file
    d3.select("body").append("div")
      .text(d.year);

    //More data manipulation
});
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50zbvLo9/).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response and the fiddle. However I have tried a lot of things and am having trouble applying this to an external tsv file as I am not using a div to hold my data. Does this work differently?