# How to load csv file to use with D3

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to use a csv file in my D3 projects. In this instance I am trying to create a new div for each year in my data. My code looks like this

```
d3.csv.parse(d3.select("ballettest.csv").text(), function(d){

    d3.select("body").append("div")
    .text(d.year);

});
```

and my data looks like this

```
year,production,company
1952,A Mirror for Witches (1952),Sadler's Wells Ballet
1937,A Wedding Bouquet (1937),The Vic-Wells Ballet
1946,Adam Zero (1946),Sadler's Wells Ballet
1958,Agon (1958),The Royal Ballet
```

I have asked this question before but unfortunately hit a dead end: [How to load tsv file to use with D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991162/how-to-load-tsv-file-to-use-with-d3) 
I am now getting the error "d is not defined." How can I fix this?

I have looked at D3 documentation but am still getting the hang of a lot of the concepts. I was using tsv, but am now using csv as I read there are issues using this with plunker.

Any more help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a less obscure way, like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
         d3.select("body").append("div").text(d.year);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

**data.csv**

```
year,production,company
1952,A Mirror for Witches (1952),Sadler's Wells Ballet
1937,A Wedding Bouquet (1937),The Vic-Wells Ballet
1946,Adam Zero (1946),Sadler's Wells Ballet
1958,Agon (1958),The Royal Ballet
```

Comment: While this solution uses less code than mine for this example, it involves more DOM operations, which means that it would be slower in more complicated examples. Binding data to selections is generally better practice. See http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data

Comment: "it involves more DOM operations" why? could you explain that? I really think is the same in terms of performance.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I am under the impression that for each iteration of the forEach loop, you're performing a DOM lookup (d3.select("body")) and then adding a new element to the DOM (.append("div")). Whereas if you do it d3 chaining, then the loop is performed with JS objects only, and once it's done, it adds them to the DOM in one go. In this case, that should mean only one DOM lookup and one element insertion operation, versus 4. Not a noticeable perf difference for this example but it adds up in larger ones.

Comment: Test it with FF, your version: 17 calls, max 60ips, min 16,34ips, avg 56,79ips. Mine: 14 calls, max 60ips, min 15,52ips, avg 56,61ips.

Comment: You did not consider what d3 is internally doing, read again the "Here’s what’s happening." step by step in your link to trace what d3 does, it is basically the same.

Comment: ...Hang on a sec, I took your word for it earlier but I just decided to do a little testing in Chrome and FF: http://jsbin.com/cihutecete/1/edit?html,js,console,output The data-bound version of the loop is completing about 10-20 times faster than the non-bound loop (depending on the number of rows in the dataset). How did you test it?

Comment: Simple HTML page, static resources and FF (37.0.1) without extensions or complements.

Comment: And the built in FF developer tools, of course (JS Analyzer)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your script to something like this:

```
d3.csv("ballettest.csv", function(data){

  d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .text(function(d){
      return d.year;
    });

});
```